# Change the background image of css:after class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a css:afer Property with background image.Is there any way to change the background image using jQuery. My css class is like this

```
.ui-btn-dis-right:after {
    width: 18px !important;
    height: 11px !important;
    background: url(../../../arrow.png) no-repeat center center !important;
    margin-top: -6px;
    content: "";
}
```

Could u please tell me how i can change the background image on click function using jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use a second class to overwrite the background:

css:

```
.ui-btn-dis-right:after {
    width: 18px !important;
    height: 11px !important;
    background: url(../../../arrow.png) no-repeat center center !important;
    margin-top: -6px;
    content: "";
}

.ui-btn-dis-right.overwritten:after {
    background: ...
}
```

javascript:

```
$(".ui-btn-dis-right").addClass("overwritten");
```